# React Native(Expo) Send image to Node (Database Postgres)

Tags: node.js, expo, image-upload

*Expo ... Pick image save url in image .. try to send formData but when api hit... undefined all attributes... on server side*
Detail::
        Get Image url, but how to send to backend , how backend get the image and save it ..
Code given below... 
where the code is wrong and also how to modified it and make it more optimized?
***React Native Code ..***

````
 let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('product_name' , Product_name);
            fd.append('company_name' , Company_name);
            fd.append('product_price' , Price);
            fd.append('product_category', category);
            fd.append('product_minimum_order' , minimum_order);
            fd.append('productimage', {uri:image , type:'image/jpeg' , name:'productimage.jpg'})
            fd.append('product_description' , feature);
            fd.append('user_id' , user_id);

            // console.log(`token ...${token}`)

            fetch('http://741297b9.ngrok.io/product/addproduct',
                {
                method:'post',
                body:fd,
                headers:{

                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${fd._boundary}`,

                }
                    }
                )

Server Code ...

const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file , cb){
        cb(null , './uploads/');
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null ,  file.originalname);
    }
})


const upload = multer({storage});

router.post('/addProduct' , upload.single('productimage'), auth ,async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        // console.log(req.file.path);
    let {
        product_name, product_category,product_price ,
        product_minimum_order,user_id,product_description,
        company_name,productimage
    } = req.body;
    // let image_url = req.file.path
    // console.log(product_name);
    // res.send(req.file.path);
    console.log(productimage);
    console.log( product_name, product_category,product_price ,
        product_minimum_order,user_id,product_description, company_name);```

undefined product_image..product_name etc....

How i can send image(data) to backend?
````

Comment: you will have to stringify the object and send as a string and parse it on the server. (If only the image value is a uri or base64, if it is file then you will have to send them seperately like `productImageUri, productImageType, ..`)

Comment: can you explain more @AneesIjaz ... Modified the Code ...thanks in advance..